# How to ovverride factory closure in Unit Test

Tags: zend-framework2

In my Module.php i have this Controller Config:

```
public function getControllerConfig() {
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Application\Controller\Persons' => function($serviceLocator) {
                $controller = new Controller\PersonsController();
                $controller->setDocumentManager($serviceLocator->getServiceLocator()->get('doctrine.documentmanager.odm_default'));
                return $controller;
            }
        )
    );
}
```

Now i want to override the factory closure in my "phpunit" test like this:

```
$this->getApplicationServiceLocator()->setAllowOverride(true);
    $this->getApplicationServiceLocator()->get('ControllerLoader')->setService('Application\Controller\Persons', function($serviceLocator) {
        $controller = new Controller\PersonsController();
        $controller->setDocumentManager($this->documentManagerMock);
        return $controller;
```

});

But this just overrides a Service i think.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

To easy:

```
$this->getApplicationServiceLocator()->setAllowOverride(true);
$this->getApplicationServiceLocator()->get('ControllerLoader')->setFactory('Application\Controller\Persons', function($serviceLocator) {
        $controller = new Controller\PersonsController();
        $controller->setDocumentManager($this->documentManagerMock);
        return $controller;
};
```